# Inject Spring context to Jersey server manually

Tags: java, spring, maven, jersey

I want to use Jersey with Spring. I'm developing standalone application (not being deployed to some webserver, but running as a console app). So I made something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig(MAIN_PACKEAGE);
    HttpServerFactory.create(BASE_URI, rc).start();
}
```

That works pretty well, but next I try to integrate Jersey Resources with Spring. As it's mentioned [here](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/spring.html) I should add **jersey-spring3** to classpath, so I add a dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

But it doesn't actually work: it doesn't even initialize the Spring context (referring the logs). I've tried to initialize SC manually:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(PATH_TO_APP_CONTEXT);
```

And this worked, but separately: context is being initialized, but the Dependency Injection is not working - I can't autowire some bean to Jersey Resource (also marked as Spring Component).

**Update**

I figured out that **jersey-spring3** works great with Grizzly server. So the working code sample is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages(MAIN_PACKAGE);
    GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
}
```

But I still wonder why integration with Spring  doesn't work if I create server using `HttpServerFactory.create(BASE_URI, rc)`...

Comment: May be if you can provide more context of the problem?

Comment: In your applicationContext.xml do you have the component scan enabled?<context:component-scan base-package="some.package" />

Comment: Sure I do. Spring initializes perfectly, but then it's context is not bind to Jersey context.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Grizzly server is working, but try adding

```
rc.property( "contextConfig", applicationContext );
```

or

```
rc.property( "contextConfigLocation", "path/to/context.xml" );
```

Depending on how you initialize the spring context (programmatically vs xml). Otherwise, I would expect it to "just work" if your xml context is named `applicationContext.xml`.

Refer to the [SpringComponentProvider](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/spring3/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/SpringComponentProvider.java) source for more details. This is the class that's responsible for bridging Spring with Jersey.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help: the SpringComponentProvider class is not even called if I use HttpServerFactory regardless properties set. But it's called if I use GrizzlyHttpServerFactory and it really needs just existence of 'applicationContext.xml' in the root of the classpath. So what's the difference between using HttpServerFactory and GrizzlyHttpServerFactory?